# using java generics properly?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, incompatibletypeerror

Im having problems with java generics.
When i use next() from the iterator it doesn't return an object of the same type i instantiated it with. So i recieve an incompatible types error.
Can anyone help?

I also recieve an Xlint warning when i compile the linked list class.

```
public class LinkedList<Type>
{

private Node<Type> sentinel = new Node<Type>();
private Node<Type> current;
private int modCount;

public LinkedList()
{
    // initialise instance variables
    sentinel.setNext(sentinel);
    sentinel.setPrev(sentinel);
    modCount = 0;
}
public void prepend(Type newData)
{
   Node<Type> newN = new Node<Type>(newData);
   Node<Type> temp;
   temp = sentinel.getPrev();
   sentinel.setPrev(newN);
   temp.setNext(newN);
   newN.setPrev(temp);
   newN.setNext(sentinel);           
   modCount++;
}


private class ListIterator implements Iterator
{
    private int curPos, expectedCount;
    private Node<Type> itNode;
    private ListIterator()
    {
        curPos =0;
        expectedCount = modCount;
        itNode = sentinel;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (curPos < expectedCount);
    }

    public Type next()
    {
        if (modCount != expectedCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException("Cannot mutate in context of iterator");
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There are no more elements");
        itNode = itNode.getNext();
        curPos++;
        current = itNode;
        return (itNode.getData());
    }
 }

}
```

Here is where the error occurs in the main class after the list is created and filled with different types of shapes.

```
shape test;
Iterator iter = unsorted.iterator();
test = iter.next();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not using raw types (e.g. plain `LinkedList` instead of `LinkedList<String>`) anywhere in your code? That would be a possible explanation of what you're describing. Please show the code where you're actually calling `next`, where the error is happening.

Comment: `private Node current;` should be `private Node<Type> current;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Iterator` is a generic interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), but your `ListIterator` is neither generic nor parameterizes `Iterator`. Start by making `ListIterator` implement `Iterator<Type>`:

```
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Type> {
    // the rest should be fine
}
```

or making `ListIterator` generic as well (more complicated):

```
private class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
    private int curPos, expectedCount;
    private Node<T> itNode;
    private ListIterator()
    {
        curPos = 0;
        expectedCount = modCount;
        itNode = sentinel;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return (curPos < expectedCount);
    }

    public T next()
    {
        // snip
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem after changing the iterator.

Comment: Aside from the iterator not implementing `remove()` the basic code compiles just fine for me. http://ideone.com/OTYxvP

Comment: if he does the latter, he should also make `ListIterator` not an inner class

Answer (score 0):

Could you post code that show how you use it?

Make sure when you use the `ListIterator` class, you generify it with `LinkedList<Something>.ListIterator`. Otherwise, an iterator of type `LinkedList.ListIterator` would be of a raw type and its `next()` will return `Object` instead.

Also don't parameterize `ListIterator`. Otherwise it would be shadowing the type variable on the outer class. Inner (non-static) classes can use outer class's type variables. Also if you did that, you would have to do `LinkedList<Something>.ListIterator<Something>` to make it consistent; you can't even do `LinkedList.ListIterator<Something>` because you can't give generic arguments to an inner class of a raw type.

Comment: Ah Thakyou both guys! it needed to be
**Iterator<shape> iter = unsorted.iterator();**
instead of 
**Iterator iter = unsorted.iterator();**